# Can't destroy azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment due to dependency in the template

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a resource group with:

- Health Data Services workspace
- DICOM service in this Health Data Services workspace

Terraform configuration files below.

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myTFResourceGroup"
  location = "westus2"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "dicomservice" {
  count               = 1
  name                = "mytfdicomservice"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  parameters_content = jsonencode({
    "healthdicomservicename" = {
      value = "mydicomservicename"
    },
    "healthworkspacename" = {
      value = "myhealthworkspacename"
    }
  })

  template_content = templatefile("dicom-template.json", {})
}
```

**dicom-template.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "healthdicomservicename": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "healthworkspacename": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": ""
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces",
      "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('healthworkspacename')]",
      "location": "westus2"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces/dicomservices",
      "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('healthworkspacename'), '/', parameters('healthdicomservicename'))]",
      "location": "westus2",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces', parameters('healthworkspacename'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the "Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces/dicomservices" resource depends on the "Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces" resource. And they are created in the right order when I use the `terraform apply` command.

```
azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.dicomservice[0]: Destroying... [id=/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/myTFResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/mytfdicomservice]
But in case of using the command `terraform destroy` I see an error:
Error: removing items provisioned by this Template Deployment: deleting Nested Resource "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/myTFResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces/myhealthworkspacename": resources.Client#DeleteByID: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: Code="CannotDeleteResource" Message="Can not delete resource before nested resources are deleted."
```

**Obviously, the terraform tries to destroy the "Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces" resource before it destroys the nested "Microsoft.HealthcareApis/workspaces/dicomservices" resource.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is correct.
A solution has been released in v3.23.0 of the Terraform Provider.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v3.23.0/CHANGELOG.md